# Correct way to search an Array instead of where

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to query search an Array with `where`? What's the correct way?

U have an association like this:

```
# Foo has many bars
Foo.first.bars
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
 @bars = []
 @datas = Foo.where(email: current_user.email)
 @datas.map { |d| @bars.push(d.bar).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:email]}%") }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @bars }
  end
end
```

Instead of `where` for Array, what is the correct query term?

Comment: do you mean find from Enumerable?, you can give it a block and search for elements in the array. [ref to doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method to filter out values in an array given a certain condition.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].select { |num| num.even? }   #=> [2, 4]
```

Or for your particular example:

```
@bars = @datas.map { |d| d.bars }.select { |b| b.name.include? params[:email] }
```

However, since you actually don't have an array of bars and would have to create it, this is simply an unnecessary step and a more straightforward solution would be:

```
@datas = Foo.where(email: current_user.email)
# @bars is an array
@bars = @datas.map { |d| d.bars.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:email]}%") }
```

or

```
# @bars is an ActiveRecord object
@bars = Bar.where(id: @datas.pluck(:id)).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:email]}%")
```